# How to debug DataStax Enterprise issues

Tags: datastax-enterprise

Where are logs located, what information is available, etc.

Original Post: http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/solr-system-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read Piotr's excellent blog post at: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/troubleshooting-datastax-enterprise